# Powershell scripting1

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am running this Script to get the directory listing

It was working few days ago but I keep having this error

```
New-PSSession : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. 
Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\DEV\Powershell3\directory-listing.ps1:11 char:38
+ $session=New-PSSession -ComputerName $servers
+                                      ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-PSSession], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSSessionCommand
 
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. 
Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\DEV\Powershell3\directory-listing.ps1:31 char:25
+ Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $scb
+                         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

```
$servers=get-content C:\temp\servers.txt
$session=New-PSSession -ComputerName $servers
$scb = {
  Write-host "working on $env:COMPUTERNAME" -ForegroundColor Red
  $volumes=Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter "drivetype=3"
  foreach($volume in $volumes) {
    $driveletter=$volume.driveletter
    if($driveLetter -ne $null) {
      $drivename=$volume.name
      (Get-ChildItem -path $drivename -Directory) |Select-Object Name,FullName
    }
  }
}
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $scb
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Instead of providing additional information in comments, please update your question directly.

Comment: @Perla, I have made a best guess at the formatting of your error information output, and of the code from your comments. Please make any necessary corrections, so that interested parties can assist you with your question. When you've done that, please delete your then invalid comment. Thank you.

Comment: The error message underlines the variable `$servers` for you and says _Provide an argument that is not null or empty_ so what do you think is the issue?

Comment: Nick.McDermaid my first though was that the server name was incorect, after maybe I am having firewall issue so not able to reach those server. but after working with the fierwall team everything looks good. Now I am a little confuse about that error

Comment: Ran a test on my local network and had no problems. Which leads me to ask how is the servers.txt file formatted? One computer name per line? Some other format?

Comment: servers.txt file is Ok . I put only one computer name and still the same error

Comment: Show us (part of) the `servers.txt` because everything points into that direction. Empty lines on top perhaps?

Comment: there was an invisible extra goodie in the txt file (hidden characters). was painful to find them but  run it fine now. Thanks everyone for your help